# Prevent Postgres column to be EMPTY using supabase & prisma

Tags: postgresql, prisma, check-constraints, supabase

I've started a new project using Prisma & Supabase but I'm facing an issue.

I have some required String columns. Is there a way to prevent those columns to accept empty string value (`''`).

Do you know if this can be done at the prisma schema level (this would be the best option I guess)? Or using subapase RLS policies?

Comment: `alter table test add constraint disallow_empty_that_column check(that_column<>'');`

Comment: Is it okay to accept `NULL`, @BghinC?  Just empty strings is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that with a [`check`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) constraint:

```sql
alter table my_table 
add constraint disallow_empty_in_that_column check(that_column<>'');
```

You can do the same with RLS:

```sql
create table test2(a text);
alter table test2 enable row level security;
alter table test2 force row level security;--applies this to table owner as well
create policy disallow_empty_in_that_column on test2 using ( a<>'' );
```

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/dh6HMbKq)